# Determine if other values are within a range of the current value

Tags: sql, ms-access, math, time

I have a table full of transactions as follows

```
Tbl_Transactions
ID       Date        Hour        Minute       Location        CardID
1        20130101    1           1            a               123456
```

Hour is 24-hour.  I want to have a SQL query which returns any transactions that happen on the same card at the same location in a +-5 minute time window.  I don't have an issue with the GROUP BY statement or anything, I just can't figure out the logic behind the 5 minute time window.

What I've done so far is create a MinutesSinceMidnight field = 60 * Hour + Minute to get a constant time scale.  Then I created RoundMin = Round(MinutesSinceMidnight/5)*5 and CeilingMin.  I then checked for duplicates using either of the two values.  However, this creates inconsistent time frames.  Minute = 53 will not match to Minute = 50 on either scale, but will match to Minute = 57, for example.

Can someone help me with the logic needed?

Comment: you want to look for a range and then you `checked for duplicates`?

Comment: Why not just convert Date, Hour and Minute to a single DateTime and work with this value rather than with three different fields?

Comment: @muratgu sorry, "checked for duplicates" was a poor choice of words.  I want to look for instances of repeated card use at the same location within a range of times from the time of the current record

Comment: @Mikhail I wasn't sure how to use DateTime fields for this purpose.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @user2395059 My point is, that if you will be able to convert values from different columns Date, Hour and Minute to one field, that will contain the complete DateTime value (for example, '2013/01/01 01:01:00' form your data sample) it will be much easier to count time difference between different rows and comparing it to 5 minutes using built-in functions for working with date/time.

Comment: @user2395059: What do you think of my solution? I can help you something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**+1 for @Mikhail,**

The example on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6dd2/1).

**Schema:**

```
create table Tbl_Transactions (
  ID int not null
  ,Date varchar(8) not null
  ,Hour int
  ,Minute int
  ,Location nvarchar(100)
  ,CardID int
)

insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (1,'20130101',1,1,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (2,'20130101',0,2,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (3,'20130201',1,1,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (4,'20130101',20,10,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (5,'20130203',1,1,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (6,'20130101',1,11,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (7,'20130102',0,1,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (8,'20121231',23,59,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (9,'20121231',23,50,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (10,'20130101',1,3,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (11,'20130101',1,5,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (12,'20130301',3,1,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (13,'20130401',1,1,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (14,'20130101',1,1,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (15,'20130101',1,2,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (16,'20130201',1,1,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (17,'20130101',20,10,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (18,'20130203',1,1,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (19,'20130101',1,11,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (20,'20130102',0,1,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (21,'20121231',23,59,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (22,'20121231',23,50,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (23,'20130101',1,3,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (24,'20130101',1,5,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (25,'20130301',1,1,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (26,'20130401',1,1,'b',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (27,'20130101',1,1,'a',123456)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (28,'20130101',0,2,'a',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (29,'20130201',1,1,'a',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (30,'20130101',20,10,'a',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (31,'20130203',1,1,'a',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (32,'20130101',1,1,'a',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (33,'20130102',1,1,'a',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (34,'20121231',23,59,'a',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (35,'20121231',23,50,'a',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (36,'20130101',1,3,'a',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (37,'20130101',1,5,'a',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (38,'20130301',1,1,'a',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (39,'20130401',1,1,'a',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (40,'20130101',1,1,'b',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (41,'20130101',1,2,'b',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (42,'20130201',1,1,'b',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (43,'20130101',20,10,'b',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (44,'20130203',1,1,'b',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (45,'20130101',1,1,'b',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (46,'20130102',1,1,'b',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (47,'20121231',23,59,'b',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (48,'20121231',23,50,'b',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (49,'20130101',1,3,'b',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (50,'20130101',1,5,'b',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (51,'20130301',1,1,'b',123457)
insert Tbl_Transactions (ID,Date,Hour,Minute,Location,CardID) values (52,'20130401',1,1,'b',123457)
```

**query**

```
declare @picktime datetime= cast('2013/01/01 00:01:00' as datetime)


SELECT
  *, 
    cast( 
        Left(Date,4)
         + '/'
         + Substring(Date,5,2)
         + '/'
         + Right(Date,2)
         + ' '
         + Cast( Hour as varchar)
         + ':'
         + Cast( Minute as varchar)
         + ':00' as datetime)
    , Dateadd(mi, -5,@picktime), Dateadd(mi, 5, @picktime) 

FROM
  Tbl_Transactions
where
    (
    cast( 
        Left(Date,4)
         + '/'
         + Substring(Date,5,2)
         + '/'
         + Right(Date,2)
         + ' '
         + Cast( Hour as varchar)
         + ':'
         + Cast( Minute as varchar)
         + ':00' as datetime)
    between
        Dateadd(mi, -5,@picktime) 
        and
        Dateadd(mi, 5, @picktime) 
    )
  and
    (CardID = 123456)
```